# Zookeeper: why instances of ClientCnxn are GC roots in MAT?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, websphere, apache-zookeeper, gc-roots

I'm looking into heap dump with Eclipse MAT and yet can not grasp why zookeeper ClientCnxn instances are marked as GC roots there.

[image]

This class is loaded by application classloader under Websphere AS. And I see quite a lot of these instances (hundreds), each of those is marked as GC root.

Any idea why these could be GC roots? These are not threads, not stack variables, etc.

Is there any way to get some information on this point from MAT?